# Filter text in Excel

Tags: excel, list, filter

I have a list of clients in excel together with their addresses and contacts. I want to separate company names of people's names. e.g. names with "LTD" or "PLC" are company names. I want to filter them separately in another sheet. How do i do that?

Comment: Are you saying the single column has both company names and names of people?

Comment: Can you show us a complete and reproducible sample in your original question?

Comment: which MS office version are you using,

Comment: yes, a single column has both company names and names of people.

Comment: I'm using MS Excel 2016